# Maven plugin for extracting internal dependency files from scm

Tags: java, sql, maven

I have a Maven project (A) which depends on some library (B).

Library uses Maven and has reachable project.scm.developerConnection URL.
Additionally this library contains some SQL scripts (DDL) which is not included into final JAR.

Is there any way to obtain those SQL files (i.e. get library pom of version specified in project A, parse it, extract developerConnection url and checkout from scm using provided URL) using Maven?

I need them:

- To run integration tests of project which uses some features of library.
- To build a distribution package for project (using maven-assembly-plugin).

Now suppose that this library is also written by me, then what is a best way (maven way?=)) to distribute SQL files?

Include them into JAR?

Note that in this case SQL files will be in JAR exclusively to make Maven build.

Answer (score 0):

If you need these resources to be available for packaging, put them in a a separate artifact that you depend on.

If you just need these resources to be available to your tests, put them in an artifact that you depend on with scope `test`. This may be a `test-jar` or a separate artifact altogether (if you prefer not to [loose transitive dependencies of your test JAR](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-jar-plugin/usage.html#How_to_create_a_jar_containing_test_classes)).

If you just need these resources to be available to Maven, e.g. for the [SQL Maven Plugin](http://mojo.codehaus.org/sql-maven-plugin/), put them in a separate artifact and have the **plugin** in your maven project ("A") depend on it.

If you know that these resources are of no reasonable use to the production environment, just *don't* put them in the final JAR of the library, since that is what goes to production.